# C Matlab Mex gateway file, printing phrs

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I want to print the values of phrs to terminal and check their data type. I thought I got the first part:

```
mexPrintf("Value: %d\n",prhs[0]);
```

But that's giving me junk. What am I missing? (Probably something obvious) Is there a way to check data types and print them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check prhs date type, i think you can use `mxGetClassName(prhs[0])`. To print its value, you need to dereference it again, as I remember correctly. For example:

```
double* data = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
mexPrintf("Value: %f\n",data[0]);
```

Note, mxGetPr, returns pointer to double, so left it in this example.

Answer (score 1):

`prhs` is an array of pointers to `mxArray`s corresponding to your inputs.
Depending on the type of your input you may use:

- if your input is a scalar:

`double input = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
printf("Value: %f\n",input);`

- if your input is an array:

`double* input = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
printf("Value: %f\n",input[0]);`

to get a pointer to your array of values, but here we print only the first value. You can use `mxGetDimensions()` to get the dimensions of the array.